# Debian Buster can't open display on the platform: Intel G6400 + Gigabyte H410M H motherboard

Tags: linux, debian, x11, graphics

Specs from my recently DIY'ed PC:

- Processor: Intel GOLD 6400  Processor
- Motherboard: Gigabyte H410M H
- GPU: Intel® UHD Graphics 610
- Three OS: Windows 10, Ubuntu 20.04, Debian 10 (Buster)
- Monitor resolution: 1920 × 1084

I have installed three OSs on it.
When I boot into Windows 10, all video displayed well.
When I boot into Ubuntu 20.04, it works fine too. 
I have not installed anything yet.

**When I boot into Debian 10-Buster, the GUI can't be displayed,
so I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>:**

```
lspci  -k | grep -i "VGA"
VGA comptible controller: intel corporation Device qba8(rev 03)
xrandr 
can't open display
```

Installing `mesa-utils` and `xserver-xorg-video-intel` does **not** help.

```
sudo apt install  mesa-utils  xserver-xorg-video-intel
startx
Xinit: giving up
Xinit: unable to connect to x server:connection refused.
Xinit: server error
```

This is the error I see in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[   264.985] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   264.985] Build Operating System: Linux 4.19.0-12-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[   264.985] Current Operating System: Linux mydebian 4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64
[   264.985] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-16-amd64 root=UUID=c13673e5-96a2-4a34-a0ae-c526a104af09 ro quiet
[   264.985] Build Date: 01 December 2020  05:59:57PM
[   264.985] xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1+deb10u2 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[   264.987] Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
[   264.992]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   264.992] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   265.001] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Apr  8 17:48:25 2021
[   265.003] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   265.003] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   265.003] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   265.003] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   265.003] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   265.004] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   265.004] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   265.004] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   265.004] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   265.004] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   265.004] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   265.004]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   265.004] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[   265.004] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   265.004] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   265.004] (II) Loader magic: 0x55a553a48e20
[   265.004] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   265.004]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   265.004]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[   265.004]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   265.004]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   265.005] (++) using VT number 3

[   265.007] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[   265.009] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:9ba8:1458:d000 rev 3, Mem @ 0xb0000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00004000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   265.009] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   265.009] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   265.010] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   265.010]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   265.010]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   265.010] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   265.010] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   265.010] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[   265.010] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   265.010] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   265.010] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   265.011] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   265.011]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.20.4
[   265.011]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   265.011]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   265.011] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   265.011] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   265.011] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   265.011]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 0.5.0
[   265.011]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   265.011]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   265.011] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   265.011] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   265.011] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   265.011]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 2.4.0
[   265.011]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   265.011]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   265.011] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   265.011] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   265.011] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   265.011] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   265.011] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   265.011] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   265.011] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   265.011] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   265.011] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   265.011] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   265.011]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.0.2
[   265.011]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   265.011] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[   265.011] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   265.011] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   265.011] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   265.011] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   265.011] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   265.011]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.0.2
[   265.011]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   265.011] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[   265.011] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   265.011] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   265.011] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   265.011] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   265.011] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[   265.011] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   265.011] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[   265.011] (EE) 
[   265.011] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   265.011] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   265.012] (EE) 
[   265.014] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Since the Ubuntu install works without problems,
I thought Debian should work also. 
Is there a driver I should install for the following GPU?

- GPU: Intel® UHD Graphics 610  in CPU-G6400

Comment: In your `lspci` output, `Device qba8` (9ba8?) is a hint that your "card" (GPU) is not identified by your kernel (i915 module most probably) => upgrade your kernel. You may need to install a kernel from Debian sid (or better: sid backports), if your kernel is already the latest version provided by Debian buster.

Comment: I presume you're logging into the console as root. Type "apt list --installed | grep xorg" - and my guess is you may need to install "apt install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu"  but then the install of amdgpu may be automatic once you have a working X11 installed - but then you may stuck in single user mode with a broken or incomplete install.

Comment: Did you try this solution? https://askubuntu.com/questions/998628/dev-dri-card0-no-such-file-or-directory xxx

Answer (score 4):

Solve the issue by upgrading the kernel:

```
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -t buster-backports upgrade
```

Reinstall grub.

```
sudo grub-install  /dev/sda
```

Reboot the PC; it can enter into the GUI interface.

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image
linux-image-4.19.0-16-amd64         install
linux-image-5.10.0-0.bpo.4-amd64        install
linux-image-amd64               install
```

Remove the old linux-image after rebooting.

```
sudo apt remove  linux-image-4.19.0-16-amd64
sudo apt remove  linux-image-amd64
```

Comment: Don't remove linux-image-4.19.0-16-amd64 until you know that the backport has no issues. It's always a good idea to retain the last couple of kernels.